# how to capture vertex name based on common edge

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Small test input :

```
A --> C
B --> C
C --> C
D --> C
E --> F
K --> F
O --> S
```

i want to display common right side value for left side value count == 2 or count == 4

like :

1. if I select A, B, E, K as source : 
   for count == 2 it should show

   Name : C, F

2.if I select A, B, C, D as source :

for count == 4 it should show

```
Name : C
```

Comment: i tried but failed .. for case-1 : v.outE(A,B,E,F,'knows').inV() and for case-2 : v.outE(A,B,C,D,'knows').inV()

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `count`.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: actually count means the no of outVertex(should be 2 or 4) which have common inVertex if match exsists then display those inVertex name.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question was answered in the gremlin-users mailing list.  Posting the link here to close the loop: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/VYC1vVL3VOA

Comment: yes am taking that input and trying to apply on my original model. thanks .:)